# issues in creating 301 redirects in Apache 2.4.3x using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, drupal-7, web-hosting

I have recently upgraded my website from http to https protocol.

I have added the following code to my .htaccess file to redirect all **http** traffic to **https** on my website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now when i search for articles on my website using google (which were previously indexed by google when the site was using http protocol.) and click on the search results it is redirected to  https://www.example.com.

For eg :

if i click on the http://www.example.com/my-article-1 (or type it in browser bar) it would redirect to https://www.example.com.

I would want to redirect all those http links to https

For eg :

if i click on the http://www.example.com/my-article-1 it should go to https://www.example.com/my-article-1

I tried creating 301 redirects in the .htaccess file

```
redirect  /my-article-1 https://www.example.com/my-article-1
```

I didnt work.The above code was added right below the first code in this question

**How do i create a proper 301 redirect for all my webpages ?**

I am using Linux hosting with Apache 2.4.33 and a Drupal 7 CMS running the website.

I have **clean URLS Enabled in my Drupal** CMS

I found out about an [article in Drupal org](https://www.drupal.org/node/38960) about putting clean URLs and tried the following combinations

```
# Various rewrite rules.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine on



 # Added by Me 


 RewriteBase /

 #RewriteRule  ^/(.*)$ https://www.domain.in/serial-programming-tutorials  [R=301,L]

 #Above statement redirects to https://www.domain.in/



 #RewriteRule  ^serial-programming-tutorials$ https://www.domain.in/serial-programming-tutorials  [R=301,L]

 #Above statement gives "The page isn’t redirecting properly" Error in Browser



 #RewriteRule  ^/serial-programming-tutorials$ https://www.domain.in/serial-programming-tutorials  [R=301,L]

 #Above statement redirects to https://www.domain.in/
```

Below is my .htaccess file.

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock))$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>



# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Added by Me 

  RewriteBase /
  #RewriteRule  ^/(.*)$ https://www.domain.in/serial-programming-tutorials  [R=301,L]
  #Above statement redirects to https://www.xanthium.in/

  #RewriteRule  ^serial-programming-tutorials$ https://www.domain.in/serial-programming-tutorials  [R=301,L]
  #Above statement gives "The page isn’t redirecting properly" Error in Browser

  #RewriteRule  ^/serial-programming-tutorials$ https://www.domain.in/serial-programming-tutorials  [R=301,L]
  #Above statement redirects to https://www.domain.in/

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!well-known/)" - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /



  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Add headers to all responses.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Disable content sniffing, since it's an attack vector.
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The first rule you posted should already do what you require, so you may have a conflict with other directives. Please posted your entire `.htaccess` file. (Incidentally, the second rule you posted is a 302 redirect, not a 301. But you should always _test_ with 302s anyway to avoid caching issues.)

Comment: @MrWhite I have made a few changes and posted the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the wrong place. It needs to go at the top of your `.htaccess` file, not at the end.

By placing it at the end, the Drupal "front-controller" has already rewritten the request to `index.php`. The later HTTP to HTTPS redirect then converts this to an external redirect (in the next round of processing) and essentially redirects everything to the document root.

The order of (mod_rewrite) directives in `.htaccess` is important.

Comment: Thank You for your help ,It is now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The order of how the statements are posted is important to the functioning of the .htaccess file as pointed out by @MrWhite.

I have changed my htaccess file as shown below to solve the problem.

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  #------------------------------------------------------------------#
  # Added by to redirect all http to https
  # Placing it here solved my problem
  #------------------------------------------------------------------#
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.in/$1 [R=301,L]
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------#


  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]



 # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Placing the below statement just below ***IfModule mod_rewrite.c*** (in .htaccess file)as shown solved all my problems

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on

      #------------------------------------------------------------------#
      # Added by to redirect all http to https
      # Placing it here solved my problem
      #------------------------------------------------------------------#
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.in/$1 [R=301,L]
      #-------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Now

http://www.domain.in redirects to https://www.domain.in
and

http://www.domain.in/tutorial-1 redirects to https://www.domain.in/tutorial-1